# Re-Indexing Schedule Job failed with Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing issue in my SQL Server 2005 SP4 as my re-jndexing schedule job failed for particular database from last month error with :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

However I am able to re-index other database with same query... Also I am able to re-index same database with Same query in my test environment.

Query for Re-Index.

```
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(255)   
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(255)  
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @fillfactor INT 

SET @fillfactor = 90 

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases   
WHERE name like ('Database_Name') 
ORDER BY 1  

OPEN DatabaseCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

   SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT table_catalog + ''.'' + table_schema + ''.'' + table_name as tableName   
                    FROM ' + @Database + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'''   

   -- create table cursor  
   EXEC (@cmd)  
   OPEN TableCursor   

   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN   

       -- SQL 2005 command  
       SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@fillfactor) + ')'  
       EXEC (@cmd)  

       FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   END   

   CLOSE TableCursor   
   DEALLOCATE TableCursor  

   FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
END  
CLOSE DatabaseCursor   
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `EXEC (@cmd)` with `SELECT (@cmd)`. Look at the results. I think you have a table name with a dash in it.

Change the query too

```
SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@fillfactor) + ')'  
       EXEC (@cmd)
```

You should use [QUOTENAME()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) on all objects. It will place brackets `[]` around the names of objects.

Comment: Thank you for reply... i am getting below error howerver i am member of SysAdmin group. Msg 1088, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
Cannot find the object "TABLE NAME" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the database name and schema name to the `ALTER INDEX`. Like you did with your TableCursor query. However, it might be better to look into using the solution from http://ola.hallengren.com/ instead of making your own solutions.